# What do I need to look out for when selecting a relay for switching audio channels

Tags: analog, audio, relay

So I heard that when using DPDT relays for something related to audio I would need to look out for what exactly to get so I don't have humming or other electrical noise while the device is in use.

The relay would be used to switch an analog signal coming from a PC between two analog audio outputs

What is it I need to look out for so I don't get electrical noise or humming?

Comment: Not the relays, but the entire circuit

Comment: Very little to worry about, audio-wise. The relays provide optimal switching with no worries about signal levels you'd get with silicon switches. You wouldn't want to put switch on a sensitive node like the inverting input of an opamp, but sounds like you're just switching strong output signals so you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay should actually be one of the most robust things in the circuit.

1. Make sure the coil is DC and not AC which could inject 60Hz noise.
2. The only real issue you might have to worry about would be one signal bleeding into the other--I'm pretty sure there is no spec on relays for this.  However, most relay contacts have pretty sizable air gaps (lots of isolation), and the bigger the relay, the bigger the gap.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Most power relays require a minimum current ("wetting current") to remove oxidation from contacts. For low level signals there is very low current so these relays will cause problems. You should use a signal relay that doesn't need wetting current, for example sealed reed or Omron G6K.

There is always some crosstalk between the coil and contacts, and a bit of capacitance, so the coil should not be fed from a power supply that has a lot of ripple or noise.

If you plan to use relays to switch outputs, presumably to the inputs of two different devices, then the device that is not receiving any signal should still have its input held at 0V. You can either use a DPDT relay to switch it between signal and ground, or just use a resistor to ground that will always be in circuit. That depends on how much isolation you want. If you want the muted channel to be absolutely muted, then a DPDT relay that shorts it to ground when not in use will provide better attenuation (but it costs more).

Answer (score 1):

Look for good low current performance .Power relays are more reliable with some minimum current .If the current is really small and you are below the arc voltage then the contact may appear open when its supposed to be closed .Old cars had points .The first transistor assisted ignition circuits used the points to drive the base of a power BJT .The needed base current for the low gain BJT provided wetting current for the points .200mA was deemed good .If you used a more complex circuit that only needed 1mA the points would not self clean and unreliability would result .Relays that switched low level audio in the bathrooms of a >300room hotel gave bad support problems .Choose your relay carefully or set up some DC wetting current scheme or consider solid state relays .

Comment: can you name an SSR that would work for switching audio signals? I thought they all used triacs or mosfets...

Comment: There are more to choose from now .Select optocoupler .Mosfet output .Select bidirectional mosfet or BOSFET .Select photovoltaic stack .

Answer (score 1):

Hum is generally not an issue, at least not from the relay.

You do want to select a sealed relay designed for signal switching. Larger unsealed relays (like the ones used on old Revox tape machines) eventually have problems due to oxide on the contacts. Omron G6 series is one typical type used.